# Exchange $_POST for isset

Tags: php, mysql, post, isset

Could you help me Exchange $_POST for isset my code ...

```
$login = $db->real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['login'])));
$password = $_POST['password'];
```

I put:

if(isset($_POST['login']))
$login = $db->real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['login'])));
else
$login = your default value;

and now i have error in next line:

error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in C:\xampp\htdocs\CDR\login.php on line 31

```
if ($_POST) {
$errors = array();

if (empty($login) || empty($password)) {
    $errors[] = '......';
}

$auth = $user->auth($login, $password);
if (!$auth) {
    $errors[] = '......';
}


if (empty($errors)) {

    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $auth;

    echo '<p class="success">.....<a href="index.php">....</a></p>';
} else {
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        echo '<p class="error">'.$error.'</p>';
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by *exchange $_POST for isset*?

Comment: What is the error / problem ? More details could be usefull.

Comment: Bitcoins are not exchanged anymore?

Comment: `$_POST` and `isset` are not interchangeable. Be more specific.

Comment: I have error Notice: Undefined variable: db in C:\xampp\htdocs\CDR\login.php on line 26

Fatal error: Call to a member function real_escape_string() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\CDR\login.php on line 26                                           and i need change $_POST to isset

Comment: you can isset($_POST['login']) but not exchange them

Comment: where u define this? `$db`

Comment: $login = $db->real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['login'])));
$password = $_POST['password'];

//czy tak jest poprawnie ??

    if ( isset($_Post["login"]) ){ 
  $login =mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST["password"])); 
  } else { 
  $password=''; 
}

Comment: For crying out loud, you're barking up the wrong tree entirely... http://stackoverflow.com/a/12769983/476, http://stackoverflow.com/a/12778634/476

Comment: @Hemikalny Please see [ask] it's unclear what your question is. Also make sure you put your information in the [edit] question and not the comments.

Comment: Rizier123 Thanks and sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean checking the post variables:

```
$login = isset($_POST['login']) ? $_POST['login'] : "";
$password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : "";
```

Also, instead of doing escaping the way you use in your question, consider using PDO (http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to check if your login post variable has any value.. You can also do this for your password post variable:

```
if(isset($_POST['login']))
 $login = $db->real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['login'])));
else
 $login = your default value;
```

Comment: Now i heve error in next line

Comment: 'if ($_POST) {
    $errors = array();

    if (empty($login) || empty($password)) {
        $errors[] = 'Wypełnij wszystkie pola';
    }

    $auth = $user->auth($login, $password);
    if (!$auth) {
        $errors[] = 'Użytkownik o podanym loginie i haśle nie istnieje';
    }


    if (empty($errors)) {

        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $auth;

        echo '<p class="success">Zostałeś zalogowany. Możesz przejść na <a href="index.php">stronę główną</a></p>';
    } else {
        foreach ($errors as $error) {
            echo '<p class="error">'.$error.'</p>';
        }
    }
}
'